# How to change background colour with a click?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

Here is the [code](https://codepen.io/Rio-4394/pen/pLqqpY) that anybody can check out.

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var x = clickMagic();

function clickMagic(){
    var count = 0;
    var colorCode = ["#FF7F50", "#E9967A", "#FFA07A", "#FFD700", "#ADFF2F", "#98FB98", "#00FFFF", "#E0FFFF", "#AFEEEE", "#87CEEB", "#DDA0DD", "#FFB6C1", "#F5F5DC", "#FFEBCD", "#FFFFE0", "#DEB887", "#FFE4B5", "#FFDEAD", "#FAF0E6"];

    return document.getElementById("bodyEdit").style.backgroundColor = colorCode[count];

    if (count == numCount - 1) {
      console.log("End of Array and rotation");

    }
    count = count + 1;
}

button.addEventListener("click", x);
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: It may be obvious from looking at the code of what you are trying to do but it would be much better if you described what you are trying to achieve and what is not working. Link to pen gives a 404

Comment: I was trying to change the background color of a HTML body on clicking a button.

Comment: A big thanks to the editor. He made it much more presentable which I messed up. I don't know your name but if possible, I would have thank you in person.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for it to do.

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var colorCode = ["#FF7F50", "#E9967A", "#FFA07A", "#FFD700", "#ADFF2F", "#98FB98", "#00FFFF", "#E0FFFF", "#AFEEEE", "#87CEEB", "#DDA0DD", "#FFB6C1", "#F5F5DC", "#FFEBCD", "#FFFFE0", "#DEB887", "#FFE4B5", "#FFDEAD", "#FAF0E6"];

var count = 0;

function clickMagic(){
  document.getElementById("bodyEdit").style.backgroundColor = colorCode[count];
  count++;
  if(count >= colorCode.length){
      console.log("End of Array and rotation");
      count = 0;
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", clickMagic);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdMaZq

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `clickMagic` when you click the button you write it this way

```
button.addEventListener("click", clickMagic)
```

Answer (score 1):

actually what you are doing here:

`var x = clickMagic();`

is assigning the returned value of the function clickMagic, so X will be undefined (because I don't see any returns) and also you wont be able to call it (because it is a function that was already fired)

you should change your code to:

`var x = clickMagic;
button.addEventListener("click", x); //this will trigger the function when clicking the button`

or with another approach:

`button.addEventListener("click", clickMagic);`

Regards.

Comment: You nailed the error. All I wanted this code to change it's color after a certain time interval all on it's own. But, that not happening. So I tried to the "basic change of Background" by trigerring it using a Button on the HTML page.

Comment: then can you mark the answer as the correct one? :) glad I could help